# Protobuf C compiler doesn't support proto3

Tags: apt, compiling

I just installed protobuf compiler and protobuf C compiler using apt install.

protoc --version shows: libprotoc 3.12.4

But as I try to compile a proto file with the --c_out option, I get:

Filename.proto: is a proto3 file that contains optional fields, but code generator protoc-gen-c hasn't been updated to support optional fields in proto3. Please ask the owner of this code generator to support proto3 optional.--c_out:

I am not sure what to do next. Could some one please help?

The OS version is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.